# Do I have to zipalign cordova release?

Tags: android, cordova

I've built a signed apk with `cordova build --release android`, should I zipalign it or did cordova already do all the job?

Comment: yes, you have to zip it by using android-studio or a shell-commands.

Comment: What would happen if I don't? @Blauharley

Comment: When you don‘t do it, then nothing happens actually because when you try to upload the apk onto play store, the apk is rejected due to missing zipalign-procedure. So you can‘t upload a non-zipped apk.

Comment: @Blauharley I tried uploading it to Play Store and it got published, i think cordova 8 automatically signs & zipaligns the apk when you build it.

Comment: Good to hear, version 8 must be doing that otherwise it would not be permitted. It seems that I use an older version ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but figured I'd pitch the answer:
Cordova let's you hook on the "after_build" event, in which you can run a .bat file which will handle the zipalign.

Example (config.xml):

```
<hook type="after_build" src="zipalign_release.bat" />
```

The "src" is relative to project root (ie: same place config.xml resides).

My .bat:

```
if exist platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release (
    cd platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release
    zipalign -f -v 4 app-release.apk app-release-zipaligned.apk
) else (
    echo Debug build.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

no, you should zipalign it using the command prompt `zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk`